# Why can't I use std::atanf on MinGW 12.2.0 and C++11?

Tags: c++, mingw, std, libstdc++, compiler-bug

From specs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan, it seems `std::atanf` exist on C++11, but on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jn37GnevM) it says 'atanf' is not a member of 'std':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float sampleOverLoaded = 200.0f;
    float outputAtan = atanf(sampleOverLoaded);
    float outputAtanStd = std::atanf(sampleOverLoaded);
    std::cout << outputAtan << std::endl;    
    std::cout << outputAtanStd << std::endl;      
}
```

What's wrong? Notice I don't want to use atanhf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug which has been resolved in November 2023 for GCC14. See **[GCC Bug 79700 - `std::fabsf` and `std::fabsl` missing from `<cmath>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700)** .

`std::atanf` is in the C++11 standard, but no one bothered adding it for the last 12 years or so. Some people also think it shouldn't exist (see the linked bug for more discussion).

For the time being, use [`std::atan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan).
It's an overloaded function which accepts `float`, `double`, and `long double`:

> ```cpp
> float       atan ( float num );
> double      atan ( double num );
> long double atan ( long double num ); // (until C++23)
> ```
>
> ```cpp
> /* floating-point-type */
>   atan ( /* floating-point-type */ num ); // (since C++23)
> ```